# Can SourcePro DB connect to Oracle using PKI?

Tags: c++, oracle, pki

Currently I am using SourcePro DB to connect to oracle database using id, password and SID via DB Access Module for Oracle OCI. However I will need to use Oracle PKI in the future. So wondering if SourcePro DB supports Oracle PKI and if anyone has done that before.

Answer (score 1):

We checked with rogue wave and currently SourcePro doesn't support DB connection using Oracle PKI.